# PHP MYSQL: Check form for blank value, get value from table 2 and use that value in table 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching and trying different methods and remain stumped. I have a form in which the user can input a size code and a dollar value on several different modules. If the user does not input a dollar value for insertion into table1, I want to be able to use a default value in table2 based on the size code and insert that value into table1 for the appropriate field when the user clicks on "Add Client".

My two tables are titled as Clients and Size. The Size table has identical field names as the Clients table for the specific fields.

I am using PHP and mysqli syntax for INSERT, UPDATE etc. and using MySQL Workbench.

I cannot hardcode a value into the HTML as this default value changes regularly and would be easier to maintain within the mysql database.

Is there a way to check if the value is empty prior to insert and if it is, get the default value from the Size table else use the user input value or is there a method within MySQL workbench to check after insert and pull the data from the Size table into the Clients table? Sorry for the long explanation, but I'm truly stumped.

An example of how I do the insert of the form into Clients is as follows:

```
$size_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['size']);
$value1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['val1']);
$value2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['val2']);

$fields = 'size_code, val1, val2';  //fieldnames in database
$values = "'$size_code', '$value1', '$value2'";

$sql = "INSERT INTO clients ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
```

This works just fine for inserting the form, but if the user leaves val2 blank I need to pull a default value from the corresponding field from the Size table and use it instead of having a blank field. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: either have a default value in db or use a ternary operator

Comment: ...and look into using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries.

Comment: Btw... doesn't this: `$fields = 'size_code', 'val1', 'val2';` throw a Parse error? Did you miss the double quotes around it when you copy/pasted it?

Comment: Sorry I meant to have just a single quote at the beginning and end and not around each field name. Typo on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SELECT` statement in the `INSERT` query, and `IF()` expressions to replace empty strings with the defaults.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (size_code, val1, val2)
        SELECT size_code, IF(? = '', val1, ?), IF(? = '', val2, ?)
        FROM sizes
        WHERE size_code = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $_POST['size'], $_POST['val1'], $_POST['val1'], $_POST['val2'], $_POST['val2']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```